# How to copy branch in MPTT Tree?

Tags: python, django

In Django I use PolymorphicMPTTModel. 
I want to copy some branch of tree from some parent node to other node. 
How to completely copy branch from one parent node to other? Not move - making complete copy with all child nodes and dependences?

Comment: How did you solve this?